# Arduino: Where is the Serial.begin symbol defined?

Tags: arduino

I am working on linux with .deb package of arduino for debian, so I can find `HardwareSerial` under:
`/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.h` 
but I am interested in locate the `Serial` definition and/or implementatio, this should be more than a `typedef` or `using` because in `HardwareSerial` class `begin` is not `static` and you can write: `Serial.begin(9600);` for example.
So some body know where is Mr `Serial`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Serial`](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/1.8.1/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.h#L143) is an object of [`HardwareSerial`](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/1.8.1/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.h#L93).